# Появляется полупрозрачная граница в один пиксель между фотками

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, img

Я столкнулась с такой проблемой. На сайте подгружены две фотографии которые стоят друг за другом. Пользователи начали жаловаться, что на macOS в safary появляется черная полоса между фотографиями. На windows в chrome, я этой полосы не наблюдаю, но на ресайзах есть подобная проблема: когда делаю ресайз, то появляется полупрозрачная граница между фотографиями. Либо у одной фотографии есть, а у другой нет и из-за этого кажется, что одна фотография вылезает за пределы. И еще иногда складывается ощущение что нижняя фотография залезает на верхнюю. Протестировала в сафари и там такая же ситуация, только полупрозрачная граница появляется на стыках фотографии и из-за этого кажется что есть черная полоса между ними.Первое фото и второе фото акая граница на винде хроме(при разных разрешениях), третья фотка в сафари

[image: Граница на windows в chrome:][image: На windows в chrome:][image: В safary:]

Использую последнюю версию chrome и safary, вот [ссылка](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-curie-jpj871?file=/src/App.vue) на песочницу.

Comment: Вертикальный размер картинки не целый. Поэтому браузеры пытаются это как-то проинтерпретировать. Кто-то лучше, кто-то хуже.